# fail including libraries in C

Tags: c

first I want to say I speak very little English, so excuse my spelling errors.

I am having a problem compiling some libraries in C using Code: Blocks as IDE

I have the following code:

```
//main.c

#include "lib1.h"

int main(){

}
```

And the "lib1.h" is

```
#ifndef GUARD_LIB1
#define GUARD_LIB1

MyTypedef variable123;

#endif
```

the "lib1.c" is

```
#include "lib2.h"
#include "lib1.h"
```

finally, "lib2.h" is

```
#ifndef GUARD_LIB2
#define GUARD_LIB2

typedef int MyTypedef;

#endif
```

But always gives me compilation error, not recognize MyTypedef in "lib1.h", any suggestions?

The error is:

```
"Unknow type name: 'MyTypedef'"
```

EIDT:

The real code that i have the problem is.

```
// EnzoLib.c
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "EnzoLib.h"




// EnzoLib.h

//blah blah blah...

//Estructuras
typedef struct {
    SOCKET sock;
    char nombre[64];
    char activo;
    struct sockaddr_in from;
} Socket;

//blah blah blah...
```

and main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <process.h>
#include "EnzoLib.h"
```

and the error:

```
C:\Users\Enzo\Documents\codeblocks\lp1\ServidorChat\EnzoLib.h|6|error: unknown type name 'SOCKET'|
```

should I add #include before #include"EnzoLib.h" in main.c? I only using functions that i declared in EnzoLib.h

EDIT2:

Is that I am trying to program a neat way. Do not put the "#includes" always on ".C files"?

Comment: The compiler can't declare a variable of type `MyTypedef` without first seeing the definition of that type.  Put the `typedef` in the header file too.

Comment: `typedef struct int MyTypedef;`? Trying to define a type called `struct int` is likely to be a brave but short-lived endeavor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When compiling `main.c`, the header `lib2.h`, which contains the definition of `MyTypedef`, is never included. Therefore, when compiling `main.c`, the compiler has *no idea* what that type is.

That is, after the preprocessor runs, the compiler sees two "translation units" (the standard calls a c file and all the headers it includes collectively a translation unit):

`main.c` becomes:

```
//main.c

#ifndef GUARD_LIB1
#define GUARD_LIB1

MyTypedef variable123;

#endif

int main(){

}
```

and `lib1.c` becomes:

```
#ifndef GUARD_LIB2
#define GUARD_LIB2

typedef struct int MyTypedef;

#endif
#ifndef GUARD_LIB1
#define GUARD_LIB1

MyTypedef variable123;

#endif
```

In `lib1.c` the compiler knows what `MyTypedef` is, but in `main.c` it does not.

If you want to use a type in a header, then the header should include its dependencies. Have `lib1.h` include `lib2.h`, so that anyone who uses `lib1.h` can tell what `MyTypedef` is.

Answer (score 0):

Move the included files from the EnzoLib.c to EnzoLib.h and only keep the #include "EnzoLib.h"

The contents of the EnzoLib.h should be something like

```
#ifndef ENZOLIB_H
#define ENZOLIB_H

#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    SOCKET sock;
    char nombre[64];
    char activo;
    struct sockaddr_in from;
} Socket;

#endif
//end of EnzoLib.h
```

Contents of EnzoLib.c should be online

```
#include "EnzoLib.h"

//Freely use the Socket structure
Socket mySocket;

//end of EnzoLib.c
```